# How to center the leaflet map

Tags: javascript, html, css, leaflet

I have a leaflet map which is has the setView() function set to Philadelphia, but it is not centered when the page is first loaded, but as soon as I move my pointer to left hand side of the tab, it centers again? Is there any way to fix this issue?

Here is a video that shows the problem:
https://youtu.be/00tGJX4MFIQ

Here is my code:

```
JS:



    var generalView = L.map('map').setView([39.985049, -75.137209], 11);

    L.tileLayer('https://tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
        maxZoom: 12,
        minZoom: 11, 
        attribution: '&copy; <a 
    href="http://www.openstreetmap.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a>'
    }).addTo(generalView);

    var bounds = L.latLngBounds([[40.085436, -75.286956], [39.850730, -75.261550], 
    [39.978227, -75.045585], [40.164526, -74.950909]]);
    generalView.setMaxBounds(bounds);
    generalView.on('drag', function() {
       map.panInsideBounds(bounds, { animate: false });
    });



    var polygon = L.polygon([
        [40.132628, -74.993758],
        [40.118835, -74.964860],
        [40.107715, -74.965412],
        [40.095888, -74.955657],
        [40.056915, -74.985074],
        [40.048661, -74.973959],
        [40.010733, -75.045703],
        [39.981755, -75.068251],
        [39.961190, -75.126685],
        [39.892362, -75.134520],
        [39.865852, -75.212061],
        [39.879824, -75.264794],
        [39.938090, -75.234661],
        [39.973699, -75.279860],
        [40.010733, -75.206411],
        [40.053993, -75.263538],
        [40.085436, -75.212111],
        [40.083860, -75.176405],
        [40.046550, -75.109801],
        [40.063368, -75.088515],
        [40.071776, -75.096754],
        [40.137950, -75.015044],
        [40.137976, -75.015294]
    ]).addTo(generalView);
CSS:
    #map {
        height: 50em; width: 75em;
        z-index: 1;
        margin-top: 10px;
        justify-content: center;
        align-items: center;
        border-radius: 10px;
    }
HTML:
    <div class="map">
            <div id="map"></div>
    </div>
```

Comment: [Works for me](https://plnkr.co/edit/4OgJiPlrrkj5D1zS).